Arch Linux version & headers package don't line up
I'm trying to write a kernel module in C on ArchLinux. Installing the linux-headers package gives me the version 6.10.5-arch1-1 but running uname -r returns 6.10.5-arch2-1
How can I install the ones for arch2-1 instead of 1-1? Otherwise everything breaks when I try to build stuff with my make file which expects arch2-1 (since it calls uname -r).
My MakeFile:
obj-m += lwiiguitar.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)/src modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)/src clean


Did you upgrade kernel recently? Did you reboot?

@pfnuesel I freshly installed the system a few days ago, and I've rebooted several times. Haven't done any upgrades yet.

It's hard to reproduce this. What gives pacman -Q linux?

@pfnuesel The output of that is linux 6.10.4.arch2-1
